# Category level issues

Tags: php, woocommerce

How can I get a specific category level from woo-commerce and display it?

My intended plan to display categories are:

```
|- Shoes                        (level 1)
   |- Nike                      (level 2)
   |- Adidas
      |- Running Shoes          (level 3)
           |- Low tops          (level 4)
                 |- products
           |- High tops

|- Hats
   |- Nike
   |- Adidas
      |- Summer hats
           |- Running hats
                 |- products
           |- Swimming hats
                 |- products
```

- First-page display: level 1 category's and level 1 subcategory's (level 2);
- Second-page displays: level 3 category's and level 3 subcategory's (level 4);
- The third-page displays: clicking on the level 4 subcategory it shows products of that category.

**I would be thankful for some guidelines on how to achieve this kind of a structure.**